# New runtime configuration fails opening with error Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled

Tags: eclipse, ecore

I am trying metamodeling tools provided in Obeo Designer Community (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Sirius/Tutorials/DomainModelTutorial)

I could generate the code but when I want to test the metamodel, it throws me:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff5767269d, pid=5954, tid=0x0000000000000307
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_211-b12) (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.211-b12 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x669d]  objc_msgSend+0x1d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/nitishpatkar/Desktop/ObeoDesigner-Community.app/Contents/MacOS/hs_err_pid5954.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I have java version 1.8.0_211 on my mac.

Any resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is caused by https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538377, which is fixed in recent versions of Eclipse but present in the one embedded in Obeo Designer.

From one of the comments it seems there is a workaround: in the launch configuration you use to launch the second instance of Eclipse/Obeo Designer (to test your metamodel), in the "Arguments" tab add "-nosplash" to the "Programs Arguments".